# R - generate all combinations from 2 vectors given constraints

Tags: r, combinations

I would like to generate all combinations of two vectors, given two constraints: there can never be more than 3 characters from the first vector, and there must always be at least one characters from the second vector.  I would also like to vary the final number of characters in the combination.

For instance, here are two vectors:

```
vec1=c("A","B","C","D")
vec2=c("W","X","Y","Z")
```

Say I wanted 3 characters in the combination.  Possible acceptable permutations would be: `"A" "B" "X"`or `"A" "Y" "Z"`. An unacceptable permutation would be: `"A" "B" "C"` since there is not at least one character from `vec2`.

Now say I wanted 5 characters in the combination.  Possible acceptable permutations would be: `"A" "C" "Z" "Y"` or `"A" "Y" "Z" "X"`. An unacceptable permutation would be: `"A" "C" "D" "B" "X"` since there are >3 characters from `vec2`.

I suppose I could use `expand.grid` to generate all combinations and then somehow subset, but there must be an easier way.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure wheter this is easier, but you can leave away permutations that do not satisfy your conditions whith this strategy:

1. generate all combinations from `vec1` that are acceptable.
2. generate all combinations from `vec2` that are acceptable.
3. generate all combinations taking one solution from 1. + one solution from 2. Here I'd do the filtering with condition 3 afterwards.
4. (if you're looking for combinations, you're done, otherwise:) produce all permutations of letters within each result.

Now, let's have

```
vec1 <- LETTERS [1:4]
vec2 <- LETTERS [23:26]

## lists can eat up lots of memory, so use character vectors instead.
combine <- function (x, y) 
  combn (y, x, paste, collapse = "")

res1 <- unlist (lapply (0:3, combine, vec1))
res2 <- unlist (lapply (1:length (vec2), combine, vec2))
```

now we have:

```
> res1
 [1] ""    "A"   "B"   "C"   "D"   "AB"  "AC"  "AD"  "BC"  "BD"  "CD"  "ABC"
[13] "ABD" "ACD" "BCD"
> res2
 [1] "W"    "X"    "Y"    "Z"    "WX"   "WY"   "WZ"   "XY"   "XZ"   "YZ"  
[11] "WXY"  "WXZ"  "WYZ"  "XYZ"  "WXYZ"

res3 <- outer (res1, res2, paste0)
res3 <- res3 [nchar (res3) == 5]
```

So here you are:

```
> res3
 [1] "ABCWX" "ABDWX" "ACDWX" "BCDWX" "ABCWY" "ABDWY" "ACDWY" "BCDWY" "ABCWZ"
[10] "ABDWZ" "ACDWZ" "BCDWZ" "ABCXY" "ABDXY" "ACDXY" "BCDXY" "ABCXZ" "ABDXZ"
[19] "ACDXZ" "BCDXZ" "ABCYZ" "ABDYZ" "ACDYZ" "BCDYZ" "ABWXY" "ACWXY" "ADWXY"
[28] "BCWXY" "BDWXY" "CDWXY" "ABWXZ" "ACWXZ" "ADWXZ" "BCWXZ" "BDWXZ" "CDWXZ"
[37] "ABWYZ" "ACWYZ" "ADWYZ" "BCWYZ" "BDWYZ" "CDWYZ" "ABXYZ" "ACXYZ" "ADXYZ"
[46] "BCXYZ" "BDXYZ" "CDXYZ" "AWXYZ" "BWXYZ" "CWXYZ" "DWXYZ"
```

If you prefer the results split into single letters:

```
res <- matrix (unlist (strsplit (res3, "")), nrow = length (res3), byrow = TRUE)
> res
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "W"  "X" 
 [2,] "A"  "B"  "D"  "W"  "X" 
 [3,] "A"  "C"  "D"  "W"  "X" 
 [4,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "W"  "X"
```

(snip)

```
[51,] "C"  "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z" 
[52,] "D"  "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z"
```

Which are your combinations.

Comment: Hmm, interesting solution! I'm just wondering..if the entries are >1 character (so instead of `vec=letters[1:3]`, `vec=month.name[1:4]`) how do I select combinations with 3 entries (obviously nchar won't work)

Comment: @jslefche: I see 2 possibilities: either go for lists, or you stick with letters first (and kind of abuse them as factor level indicators), and once you have your combinations, convert the letters to the months

Comment: @beleites: I used `strtrim` to restrict the number of characters in each vector, and used those to generate the combinations